# When scraping, console.log shows the data but it’s not returned

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, axios, cheerio

This is the working code :)  BUT now I cannot figure out to get into an array of seperate objects......

```
getGAS: function(url) {
    var self=this;
rp(options)
 .then(($) => {
  let gasset = [];

  $('.stations-list').each(function(i) {
   gasset[i] = {}

   gasset[i]['name']= $('.name').children('a').text(),
   gasset[i]['ppg']= $('.ppg').children('a').text(),
   gasset[i]['dist']= $('.dist').children('a').text(),

   gasset.push({name: gasset[i]['name'], ppg: gasset[i]['ppg'], dist: gasset[i]['dist']});
    console.log(gasset);
    });

  // console.log(gasset);
   self.sendSocketNotification("GAS_RESULT", gasset);
  })
 .catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
```

});
    },

This is my return ...

[ { 
name: '1. Kwik Fill #372. Express Mart #3533. Byrne Dairy #664. Express Mart #3225. Sues Pine Valley Busymart6. Speedway #7749 (discount Available)7. Express Mart #3708. Byrne Dairy #19. Dandy Mini Mart #6310. 7-eleven #35122',

ppg: '$3.099$2.959$2.959$2.959$3.359$3.159$2.959$2.959$2.959$3.159',

dist: '1.68 miles2.09 miles2.23 miles2.49 miles2.76 miles2.92 miles3.09 miles3.31 miles4.25 miles4.36 miles' },

{ name: '1. Kwik Fill #372. Express Mart #3533. Byrne Dairy #664. Express Mart #3225. Sues Pine Valley Busymart6. Speedway #7749 (discount Available)7. Express Mart #3708. Byrne Dairy #19. Dandy Mini Mart #6310. 7-eleven #35122',
    ppg: '$3.099$2.959$2.959$2.959$3.359$3.159$2.959$2.959$2.959$3.159',
    dist: '1.68 miles2.09 miles2.23 miles2.49 miles2.76 miles2.92 miles3.09 miles3.31 miles4.25 miles4.36 miles' } ]

Which I'm having 2 issues with....for some reason I'm getting all the data twice and I cannot get it into 1 array with objects for each....

Comment: No value returned from what?  `getGAS()` has no return value.  You would have to return the axios promise from that.

Comment: I understand that but it works right to this part "console.log("Gas Prices");" and outputs that but nothing after that.....that's where I'm having the issue.  Man being new to things and trying to learn you get no mercy around here.

Comment: Well, you would have gotten more feedback if you had included that EXACT info in your question.  There's a bunch of code and not really even a question in your question and no specifics about what you observed or what you did to debug it.  There was just not much to go on.  You have to give us the right info for us to be able to understand what the exact problem is and what steps you've already taken to debug it.  That's how we can help you the best.  Unfortunately, this is true no matter how much experience you have.  So, what is your actual question?  Is it something about a return value?

Comment: When you do `console.log(station);`, there is no variable defined in the code you show named `station` so it appears that might be an error.  What exactly do you see in the console?  Did you mean to do: `console.log(devtoList[i].station)`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual question you mean to ask.  Right now, it says you get your `console.log()`, but returns no data.  But, there's not even a single `return` statement in the `getGAS()` so of course it returns no data.  We don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Also, your CSS selector is wrong.  `$('stations-list')` should be `$('.stations-list')`.  Because `stations-list` is a class name, you must have a `.` at the beginning of it.

Comment: Same with `$(this).find('name').text().trim()` which should be `$(this).find('.name').text().trim()` or perhaps even `$(elem).find('.name').text().trim()`.

Comment: And, you have too many things with a class of `name` so you probably aren't going to get exactly the right stuff with that selector either.  The `$.each()` loop needs to be rewritten, but I'll wait to comment further until you clarify what question you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: A selector that could work is `$(".stations-list a.name").each(...)`.  That would give you the links in your table and you could then just get the `.text().trim()` from each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Inside getGAS method provide return value e.g.

```
getGAS: function(url) {
//code
//at end 
return devtoList;
}
```

Comment: getGAS: function(url) {
  var self=this;
    rp(options)
     .then(($) => {
   let gasset = [];
        
   $('.stations-list').each(function(i, elem) {
    gasset[i] = {}
    
    gasset[i]['name']= $('.name').children('a').text(),
    gasset[i]['ppg']= $('.ppg').children('a').text(),
    gasset[i]['dist']= $('.dist').children('a').text(),
    gasset.push(gasset[i]);
     console.log(gasset[i]);
  });
  
      // console.log(gasset);
    self.sendSocketNotification("GAS_RESULT", gasset);
      })
     .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 },

Comment: This won't really help because there's async stuff going on in this function.  If they're trying to return the value, then they have to return the promise and make the desired value be the resolved value of the promise.

Comment: @John - It does absolutely no good to dump a bunch of multi-line code into a comment with no explanatory text.  We can't read it or tell what you're trying to say.  Use explanatory text or single lines of code only in comments.  If you have to communicate multiple lines of text, then use the "Edit" link to add them to the end of your question with explanatory text and then post a comment tell people what you added.  This answer won't work anyway.

Comment: Sorry about the bad code dump...... I did manage to get it working now just have to figure out how to get into json objects..... I'll edit my question with the data that works :)